# $(window).scroll(function() doesn't fire, always undefined

Tags: jquery, scroll, document-ready, window-load

I can't understand why on my localhost this doenst work at all?
The $(window).scroll(function() won't fire. Am I missing something? is this code a total disaster?

```
var module =  {
    init: function () {
      this.fixHeader();
    },

    fixHeader: function () {

      var sticky = $('.header'),
      stickyHeight = $(sticky).outerHeight(),
      stickyTop = $(sticky).offset().top,
      stickyBottom = stickyTop + stickyHeight;

       $(window).scroll(function(){
        console.log('dasdasdasdasdas');
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(scrollTop > stickyBottom){
            $(sticky).addClass('sticky');
        }else{
            $(sticky).removeClass('sticky');
        }
      });

        $(sticky).on('click', '.logo', function(){
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0} ,'slow');
        });


    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  module.init();
});
```

Comment: No need to wrap sticky with $() it's already a jQuery object

Comment: What exactly is undefined?

Comment: Works as-is for me, so long as an element with the class `header` exists: http://jsfiddle.net/nF4JT/

Comment: if I do module.fixHeader(); on the console log is undefined

Comment: It's seems to be compass my problem! I'm investigating why